# Log 4j Conversion Pattern not working kafka.producer.KafkaLog4jAppender in Kafka.0.8.1.1

Tags: java, logging, apache-kafka

I am trying to use KafkaLog4jAppender to write to kafka and also a file appender to write to a file. The conversion pattern works for the file, but for the kafka appender it is not working

The output of the file appender is **2014-09-19T22:30:14.781Z INFO  com.test.poc.StartProgram Message1**
But the Kafka appender has output as **Message1**

Find below my log4j.properties file

```
log4j.rootCategory=INFO
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH
log4j.appender.file.File=logs/test.log
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'}{UTC} %p %C %m%n

log4j.logger.com=INFO,file,KAFKA

#Kafka Appender
log4j.appender.KAFKA=kafka.producer.KafkaLog4jAppender
log4j.appender.KAFKA.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.KAFKA.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'}{UTC} %p  %C %m%n

log4j.appender.KAFKA.ProducerType=async
log4j.appender.KAFKA.BrokerList=localhost:9092
log4j.appender.KAFKA.Topic=test`enter code here`
log4j.appender.KAFKA.Serializer=kafka.test.AppenderStringSerializer
```

Comment: did you fix this? if so can you share the appropriate configuration.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known Kafka bug; the fix is in Kafka 0.8.2:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-847